# If image source not found show first two letters of the item in the list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to angular and Ionic 3. I have country flags in a directory. I am trying to list the country name with its flag as shown in the image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJBhf.jpg

If a particular country flag image is not found, the first two characters of the country name has to be displayed in place of image.

Till now I have tried this, but not able to achieve the required result. Can anyone help me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let country of countryList> 
<ion-avatar item-left>       

<img src="assets/imgs/flags/{{country}}.png" *ngIf="imgSrc;else customImg" (error)= "imgSrc=false">

<ng-template #customImg>
 <span *ngIf="!imgSrc" class="circle">{{country.substring(0, 2)}}</span>
</ng-template>

</ion-avatar>
<p>{{country}}</p>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Property Binding `[alt]="country.substring(0,2)"` .
**Modified Code**

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let country of countryList"> 
<ion-avatar item-left>       

<img src="assets/imgs/flags/{{country}}.png" [alt]="country.substring(0,2)">

</ion-avatar>
<p>{{country}}</p>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You can bind a method to `error`  extract the substring and display it accordingly
**Page/Component**

```
   export class HomePage {

    public error:string[]=[];
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

      }
    setValue(country:string,index:number)
    {
      console.log(country);
      this.error[index]=country.substring(0,2);
    }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let country of countryList; let i=index"> 
<ion-avatar item-left>       

<img src="assets/imgs/flags/{{country}}.png" (error)="setValue(country,i)" >

<ng-container >

 <span *ngIf="error[i]?.length" class="circle">{{error[i]}}</span>
</ng-container>
</ion-avatar>
{{country}}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work,but I need to add CSS styling for example background color and I want the text to be center of a circle.

Comment: Mate I have Updated My answer

Comment: Thank you very much Vikas. This is what I exactly wanted. Thanks for taking your time out and helping me.

Comment: Glad I could Help you mate Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `alt` attribute (actually you should always do that, in order to provide information for people with visual disabilities for example). So you don't need any conditional statements here, just fill in all the images' `alt` attribute with the abbreviation you want to show if the image is not found.